# How can I do something (like starting my 2nd activity) when user enable's wifi even when my app is not open?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am totally confused how to perform this action. I found several ways but no answer. please help me with some code or project. I want my activity starts anywhere I turn on Wifi  even when my app is not open.

Answer (score 1):

You know, you already have a clue on what you will do, so googling it would be really easy. I suggest referring to some SO questions and answers and going to developer.android.com to browse the documentation. basically you want to:

1. Start a service on boot, that listens for when the wifi is turned on/off.
2. Create and send a broadcast to your app
3. Define a BroadcastReceiver that launches your app or another intent

Comment: Related Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032376/wifi-broadcastreceiver-onreceive